how to fix:configure: error: *** A compiler with support for C++11 language features is required
when i compile and install gcc-11.1.0,i excute by steps:

how to fix:configure: error: *** A compiler with support for C++11 language features is required.

1. dowlonad gmp-6.1.0 
    ./configure --prefix=/usr/local/gmp && sudo make install
2. download mpfr-3.1.4
    ./configure --prefix=/usr/local/mpfr && sudo make install
3. download mpc-1.0.3
    ./configure --prefix=/usr/local/mpc && sudo make install
4. download isl-0.18 
    ./configure --prefix=/usr/local/isl && sudo make install
5. update env file:
   echo "export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/usr/local/mpc/lib:/usr/local/gmp/lib:/usr/local/mpfr/lib/:/usr/local/isl/lib" >> ~/.bash_profile 
    source ~/.bash_profile
    sudo ldconfig
6. cd gcc-11.1.0
    ./configure --prefix=/usr/local/gcc-7.3.0 --enable-languages=c,c++ --disable-multilib --with-system-zlib --disable-multilib --with-gmp=/usr/local/gmp --with-mpfr=/usr/local/mpfr --with-mpc=/usr/local/mpc --with-isl=/usr/local/isl

then i meet configuer failed:

  I spent one day to try to fix this problem, but i failed.
how to fix this problem?

Cannot you just use your distro's package manager to install whatever you need?

I think that your /usr/local/bin/clang++ is broken. A well-built clang++ would need to be very old not to accept -std=c++11 and it certainly should accept -g (= generate debugging information). Did you also build it yourself? if so why?
